# How to on img click, show just one, and hide other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on project, and got stuck with JS.
Please before you read text, see the picture.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAaoa.png)

I want to make a slider (And I did), and now when I click on a circle, I want to show content-box only with the same color, and others should be hidden.

e.g. when I click on .imgRed, I want only #red to be displayed, others, #blue and #black to be `display: none;`.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please add your html / js for us to see what you came up with?

Comment: Maybe even some CSS if there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create a working snippet according to the image, where I used:

- A class for the circles, another class for the bars,
- The circles got a `data-color` attribute that will target the bar to be displayed on click.

Here it is:

```js
// When clicking a circle, use the data-colo to display the correct bar
$('.circle').click(function() {
    $('.bar').hide();
    var color = $(this).data('color');
    $('#' + color).show();
});

// Trigger the click event on load:
$('.imgRed').trigger('click');
```

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 8px 16px;
  border: 30px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.bar {
  display: none;
  margin: 8px 16px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 250px;
}

.imgRed {
  border-color: red;
  background-color: red;
}

.imgBlack {
  border-color: black;
  background-color: black;
}

.imgBlue {
  border-color: blue;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle imgRed" data-color="red"></div>
<div class="circle imgBlack" data-color="black"></div>
<div class="circle imgBlue" data-color="blue"></div>
<br><br>
<div class="bar imgRed" id="red"></div>
<div class="bar imgBlack" id="black"></div>
<div class="bar imgBlue" id="blue"></div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is awesome. Thank to you, Do you additionally know how to on load, show only the first one e.g. red?

Comment: @Adnan Sure, you can use `display: none;` in the CSS of the `.bar`s, and trigger the `click` event of the `redImg` on load, like that: `$('.imgRed').trigger('click');` … I've updated the snippet that way.

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You probably know what you should do but you are not confident about it. You should hide others but the one that you want to stay present.
For example for red you should do:

```
$('.imgRed').click(function() {
    $('#red').show();
    $('#black').hide();
    $('#blue').hide();
}
```

and repeat for all of the others.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.imgRed').click(function(){
    $('#red').show();
    $('#blue,#black').hide();
});
```

now when you click on all elements with class .imgRed only those with ID red will be visible.

the same you have to do with your other classes;